# How can this possibly be a good audit?

Tags: discussion, review-audits

Come on, really?

https://stackoverflow.com/review/triage/15107504

Honestly, it's not worth it. The draconian bans imposed for failing these are just convincing the experienced reviewers to stay away.

Comment: Audits are chosen automatically from questions where there was a consensus. It apparently didn't have any down votes or flags. It has a down vote now so it won't be used as an audit again.

Comment: Yeah, I DV'ed and VTC'ed, which is my automatic response to bad audits.  It's still frustrating given that two of those over a couple of days and you get banned.  The site is drowning in crap and people trying to clean it up are penalized.  Why bother?

Comment: I could quibble over your choice of "unsalvageable". It looks to me like there is a reasonable question buried in here, and that question would be extracted out by an edit. It wouldn't even have to be the original author that edited it. Anyone could clarify the wording and add sample code that demonstrates the problem more clearly. So I would have chosen "Requires Editing". Of course, that would have failed the audit, too, and I would have been upset, too.

Comment: We are all busy people. I believe it is the responsibility of the asker to provide a clear problem. The question text did contain words that shows they have some knowledge in multithreaded code. However I agree with @JimGarrison that it is not presented in a way that many people would like to triage.

Comment: It doesn't have very many views, less than 70. Does anyone know if view count is considered when picking audit questions? If not, perhaps adding that will help reduce the risk of getting questions where there is a consensus that reviewers are likely to disagree with. Someone may have to look at [disputed audits](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/disputed-review-audits) to be sure though I don't know if it's even possible to view historical data on view counts.

Comment: @BSMP that is not public in SEDE and I doubt it is even available for staff, except from the logfiles.

Comment: I don't seriously understand what's wrong with the question. Unsalvageable? Could you please explain why you think so?

Comment: Never mind. I see that the original ideals of SO no longer apply due to the sheer weight of questions that amount to _"do my homework ASAP"_, _"here's a vague problem, I'm too lazy to research it myself or even pay attention to the potential dups shown"_ and _"I'm too entitled to pay attention to site guidelines"_.  I recognize this has become tilting at windmills and have asked for this question to be deleted.

Comment: @CodyGray whatever reasonable is there, it's buried too deep. The way the question is presented currently, it's too broad and unclear

Answer (score 0):

That is a good question, and marking it "Unsalvageable" is plainly wrong. I agree that the review system is flawed and misguided, but this is not a good example of why. In this case, giving you a light slap is warranted. You should not be flagging questions like this.

Comment: "What about ReentrantLock" the author asks. That's not a good question but a trigger for research and experimentation. The true more specific question which does not require writing up a manual to cover all the corner cases tipped in there, follows from that. I join the "too broad" crowd myself, the OP is fully capable of narrowing it down to a good question. Regardless, the flag was indeed wrong.